# Twitter API or Library to remember the session

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been going through the Twitter API, but they are not as friendly as Facebook. My requirement is remember the authentication in the server / db and post user messages to the timeline without invoking twitter UI. Ofcourse I know we need to allow first time authentication via Twitter UI.

I'm not sure where to start and 2 days of Google search didn't end at any place where I can get started. Is there any document, resources, library (PHP or JavaScript) available to execute such scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [wonderful tutorial](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_twitter_with_php) on how to auto post via PHP to Twitter. Check it out